# Chapter 11 Micheal Hartl error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do Sample App on book Michael Hartl and in Chapter 11 have some error

Showing /home/andrey/RoR/sample_app/app/views/shared/_stats.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Unknown validator: 'PresenseValidator'

Extracted source (around line #5):

5<%= @user.followed_users.count %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/andrey/RoR/sample_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/models/relationship.rb:4:in `<class:Relationship>'
app/models/relationship.rb:1:in`'
app/views/shared/_stats.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_shared__stats_html_erb__765092261__621887978'
app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:8:in`_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__496074363__614039518'

user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", class_name: "Relationships", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+-.]+@[a-z\d-]+(.[a-z]+)*.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

has_secure_password

validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

def feed
    Micropost.where("user_id = ?", id)
  end

def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy!
  end

private

```
def create_remember_token
  self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
end
```

end

stats.erb.html

```
 <% @user ||= current_user %>
 <div class="stats">
 <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
 <strong id="following" class="stat">
  <%= @user.followed_users.count %>
 </strong>
 following
 </a>
 <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
 <strong id="followers" class="stat">
  <%= @user.followers.count %>
 </strong>
 followers
 </a>
 </div>
```

relationship.rb

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presense: true
  validates :followed_id, presense: true
end

Comment: should be a typo? "presense" != presence

Comment: Can you post your `Relationship` model?

Answer (score 5):

You have a misspelling in your relationship.rb

```
validates :follower_id, presense: true 
validates :followed_id, presense: true
```

should be

```
validates :follower_id, presence: true
validates :followed_id, presence: true
```